# How to store unique multilingual texts in SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) in universal way?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-ce, multilingual

I use SQL Server CE 3.5 in DirectTable mode.

Let's define uniqueness of characters. Two characters are equal if they are exactly the same (like 'a' and 'a'). Such characters as 'A'  and 'a' are not equal. Two strings are equal if they consist of the same characters in the same order, so for example 'foo' is NOT equal to 'ofo' or 'Foo'.

Now, please notice I don't care what ISO committee says, I need such very exact matching. The purpose is storing multilingual texts (words) in database.

**QUESTION** -- the question is how to do it? I don't know in advance anything about the language, one user could store words only from Polish vocabulary, and the other could store words from several languages at the same time (and this is valid).

If you think this problem is trivial, you are mistaken. I already found out that SQL Server CE treats double 's' the same as single character 'ß', which is completely not acceptable. I found some workarounds which forces collation on comparison, but I cannot use them:

- they are assuming SQL queries, this is no-go for me, it would slow me down
- they are assuming in advance the problem is with German language, I cannot assume such thing

I search in database, but I don't use ordering, so I don't care if the showing entire table with words is in "correct" order or not. All I care is when I seek text in table, I get match if the words are **REALLY** equal, not similar.

### Workaround

Since for current project I needed working solution for "yesterday", I kept text string fields in database without any change, but on read I convert them from base64 to utf8, and on write vice-versa. A little overkill for space, but I can live with it, and for what's important with case sensivity ON I am completely independent of MS comparison implementation, collations, etc. Every individual Unicode character is encoded differently.

I am all ears though for more elegant solution (if any such exists).

Comment: What about unicode normalization, e.g. the Angrstoem character which has three different but equivalent representations ("U+C5" [Latin-1 supplement], "U+212B" [letter-like symbol], "U+41 U+30A" ['A' plus diacritic]). How do you want to handle this?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, you already answered yourself, since you (human being) can tell the difference, they are different.

Comment: Well, Unicode actually mandates that all those compare equal, and in fact I as a human can_not_ distinguish those visually (only by inspecting the binary representation). Moreover, your input device is not required to generate any particular version, so how can someone type in the character and match it reliably?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, what matter here is not playability but reliability. When I put byte 0x16 in database I expect to get byte 0x16 in return, not 0x98 even if they are visually the same. I need sharp-shooter precision here. IOW: think in terms of bits of text, not the appearance on the screen.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should store each character as a binary value ?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can make the database case sensitive, so A <> a. SQL CE stores unicode, so that would allow you to store all required characters. Are you doing compares in .NET or using a index?

Comment: Case sensitivity is of course trivial, and I've already set it ON. Seeking (comparison) is done by SQL CE engine.

Comment: What is the remaining problem then? Could you give a minimal and self-contained example that exhibits the problem?